# All classes last modified date got changed from production

Tags: apex, deployment

In production all classes last modified date has been changed to a same date. We have 6MB of apex code in production. We haven't done such huge deployment. We do it by changeset and sometimes we use eclipse. Is there any possibility by which all classes would be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you are using eclipse then you can modify apex class in production.

I think anyone saved your workspace to server(i.e. Deploy to server). not sure only guessing this can be a reason.

Check login history may be you will get something.

Comment: this is something weird. Yes this is one of the possibility but, can you guess some other ways by which this could happen.

Comment: I want to clear one thing here. You can't modify class in PROD directly it can be done using deploy to server or changset or force.cim migration toolkit. Please check your deployment history

Comment: @Himanshu. Can you pls open any production org  class in eclipse and try to save.

Comment: @Himanshu - You most certainly can create / edit / delete classes directly in production from an IDE. There are caveats but it can be done using the tooling API